# How should I do when I need to call a func. that creates a node a list, from another func., but that first func. takes a pointer as an parameter?

Tags: c, pointers, doubly-linked-list

Anyway - what I mean is this:

I have a "addToEmpty" function, that adds a node to an empty doubly linked list...

```
void addToEmpty(struct node **ptr, int value)
{
    struct node *newNode;
    newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    (*ptr) = newNode;
}
```

And I call it from main with this:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct node *head = NULL;

    addToEmpty(&head, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

So far, so good... but then, I got another function that inserts nodes at the beginning of a linked list:

```
void insertAtBeg(struct node **ptr, int value)
{
    struct node *newNode;
    newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if(*ptr == NULL) // om listan är tom
    {
        addToEmpty(&head, 10);  //  <--- This here doesn't work anymore
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->data = value;
        (*ptr)->prev = newNode;
        newNode->next = *ptr;
        (*ptr) = newNode;
    }
}
```

And there, the first if-statement, checks if the list is actually empty, and if it is, I would like to use the addToEmpty function, but I can't and I don't really understand why, as I barely understand all of this with lists and pointers and references and whatnot... Can somebody please help me? and explain why it is not working for me?

I tried to put *, **, nothing, and.. that's it I guess, instead of the "&", in front of head, when calling the function, but nothing worked...

Answer (score 0):

In your `if` block you're not using the function parameters. There's no `head` variable in `insertAtBeg()`.

```
if(*ptr == NULL) // om listan är tom
{
    addToEmpty(ptr, value);
}
```

Comment: hah, that's very true! I added "struct node *head = NULL;" in the beginnig of the instertAtBeg function, and it all started to work just fine... I am guessing that I could just rename the *newNode to head instead too...

Thanks!

Comment: There's no need to do that. Just do what I said.

Comment: or I could just write what you wrote instead..